# Create [x86-64] synonym for [amd-64]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

On Stack Overflow, the [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) tag is the main tag for questions about 64 bit extensions to the Intel x86 architecture. The [amd64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd64) tag is a synonym.

Here on Code Review, the [amd64](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amd64) tag exists (and only has 6 questions), but has no synonyms. The [x86-64](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) tag does not exist at all.

I recently looked at a question about 64 bit assembly that was tagged with [assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) and [x86](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x86). When I went looking for an `x86-64` tag to add to it, I couldn't locate one. I did find [amd64](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amd64), but that is not something I would think to look for, particularly because of the existence of `x86-64` on Stack Overflow.

Should the `x86-64` tag be created as a synonym of [amd64](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amd64)? This would help users familiar with Stack Overflow find the tag here.

Or, for consistency with Stack Overflow, should `x86-64` be the main tag with `amd64` as a synonym?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**

This seems like a good idea. I can understand why the confusion happens when compared with Stack Overflow. Additionally, the revision history on the tag itself on Code Review shows that the tag always said that [the `x86-64` alias is reasonable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/212758/revisions).

Unfortunately, only those people who have a score of at least 5 in the actual tag involved are allowed to suggest the alias... in this case, [no users have that privilege](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/amd64/topusers), so moderator intervention is needed.